# How to format text in PDFkit

Tags: pdfkit, node-pdfkit

it is possible to format text in pdfkit? Like bold, recursive and all the other things?[Demo](http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html)

I cannot find anything in the docs

Answer (score 3):

If look in the file node_modules > pdfkit > js > font > data.
there are the standard fonts you can easily include with

```
      doc.font('Helvetica-Bold');  // as an example
```

If you want to use ur own font: 
PDFKit supports embedding font files in the TrueType (.ttf), TrueType Collection (.ttc), and Datafork TrueType (.dfont) formats.To change the font used to render text, just call the font method. If you are using a standard PDF font, just pass the name to the font method. Otherwise, pass the path to the font file, or a Buffer
 containing the font data. If the font is a collection font (.ttc and .dfont files), meaning that it  contains multiple styles in the same file, you should pass the name of the style  to be extracted from the collection.
Here is an example showing how to set the font in each case.

```
      doc.font('fonts/PalatinoBold.ttf')
```

or

```
      doc.font('fonts/Chalkboard.ttc','Chalkboard-Bold')
```

Comment: what if font is hosted online or it's a custom font online?